Unable to limit external-dns to a specific ingress class
I have 2 ingress classes, one for AWS ALB, and the other for Nginx:
k get ingressclass -A
NAME    CONTROLLER             PARAMETERS   AGE
alb     ingress.k8s.aws/alb    <none>       5h
nginx   k8s.io/ingress-nginx   <none>       3h34m

I have the following TF in my eks_blueprints_addons module:
external_dns  =  {
  chart_version  =  var.external_dns_helm_chart_version
  role_name  =  "${local.cluster_name}-external-dns-iam-role"
  role_name_use_prefix  =  false
  policy_name  =  "${local.cluster_name}-external-dns-iam-policy"
  policy_name_use_prefix  =  false
  values  = [templatefile("${path.module}/helm/external-dns.yaml", {})]
}

And in my external-dns.yaml:
annotationFilter: ingress.class=alb
provider: "aws"
labelFilter: ingress-class in (alb)

I am trying 2 different ways(have tried one, then the other) to limit external-dns to only provision DNS entries only on my ALB class, but no matter what I do, whenever I deploy a Nginx ingress, it creates DNS entries with an A record to the internal IP of my nginx-ingress-controller, which is then broken.
When I describe my external-dns deployment, I just don't see those settings being applied anywhere:
k describe deploy external-dns -n external-dns
Name:               external-dns
Namespace:          external-dns
CreationTimestamp:  Tue, 16 Jul 2024 15:16:34 -0500
Labels:             app.kubernetes.io/instance=external-dns
                    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                    app.kubernetes.io/name=external-dns
                    app.kubernetes.io/version=0.14.2
                    helm.sh/chart=external-dns-1.14.5
Annotations:        deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
                    meta.helm.sh/release-name: external-dns
                    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: external-dns
Selector:           app.kubernetes.io/instance=external-dns,app.kubernetes.io/name=external-dns
Replicas:           1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 1 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:       Recreate
MinReadySeconds:    0
Pod Template:
  Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/instance=external-dns
                    app.kubernetes.io/name=external-dns
  Service Account:  external-dns-sa
  Containers:
   external-dns:
    Image:      registry.k8s.io/external-dns/external-dns:v0.14.2
    Port:       7979/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Args:
      --log-level=info
      --log-format=text
      --interval=1m
      --source=service
      --source=ingress
      --policy=upsert-only
      --registry=txt
      --provider=aws
    Liveness:     http-get http://:http/healthz delay=10s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=2
    Readiness:    http-get http://:http/healthz delay=5s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   external-dns-6c857c8749 (1/1 replicas created)
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age   From                   Message
  ----    ------             ----  ----                   -------
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  25m   deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set external-dns-6c857c8749 to 1

